# Python Fiona affecting external GDAL binaries?

Tags: python, gdalwarp, fiona

Curious if anyone else has encountered this before and may have an explanation:

In my Python workflow, I'm importing `fiona` (1.8.4) to manipulate shapefiles, and then later downstream I'm shelling out to `gdalwarp` to reproject a GeoTIFF using python's `subprocess.check_output` to make system calls..

Most of the time, this works flawlessly. But for certain EPSG codes, I'm seeing some very odd behavior I'm hoping someone can shed light on. With EPSG 26749 as target, the reprojected boundaries are only correct if I don't `import fiona` in the lines above.

My suspicion is that my pip install of Fiona is pointing to out of date GDAL libraries lurking around my system, but what I really don't understand is how this could possibly be affecting the behavior of the call to the `gdalwarp` binary outside of Python?

While I dig in and try to fix my Fiona GDAL dependancies, I would love to know if anyone can explain how importing a gdal-dependent module in Python could then affect the behavior of an external GDAL call... but only for the duration of the Python script?

Comment: How are you "shelling out" the `gdalwarp` call?

Comment: Just using python's `subprocess.check_output` to make system calls.

Answer (score 1):

Importing Fiona can set some GDAL library paths, so you may want to run your subprocess [using a copy of your original environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231227/python-subprocess-popen-with-a-modified-environment) before the Fiona import changes anything.

```
import subprocess, os
my_env = os.environ.copy()
import fiona
# do your thing
subprocess.check_output(my_command, env=my_env)
```